# Is it ethical to put "buy me a beer" with bitcoin key user's profile page?

Tags: discussion

What is SO's approach towards putting a bitcoin key with "buy me a beer" text in a user's profile page? Is it against the rules of SO?

Comment: Why would it be against the rules? It's just a suggestion on a profile, it is not even unethical.

Comment: Some could think of it as spam? Just wanted to make sure before doing something that could make me banned...

Comment: Hey, that's a pretty good idea...

Comment: I might be living under a rock here, but *what?*

Comment: @zenpoy, why, do you advertise a specific brand of beer?

Comment: @zenpoy - If it were on an answer, then I could definitely see an issue. On a user's profile page? That should be fine.

Comment: @ChrisForrence On an answer it would just be offtopic noise. Not against any rules, but something to remove from a post just like any other noise.  Certainly nothing worth any disciplinary action.

Comment: The profile "about me" section is the only place users can "have fun". As long as it's not offensive, anything goes there. So it's totally legit to ask for beer/money there.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, this would be funny...

Comment: I have my Amazon wish list in mine. Hasn't worked yet, but I have high hopes. Perhaps potential donors are put off by the buttless leather chaps.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not at all against any rules. The user is not forcing you to buy a beer. And if the user were to push you within answers and comments to do so, you might have a point. (Feel free to flag the comment or edit the post, if that is the case) But profiles are much more free in that regard.

I know of various users who include links to Paypal or to Amazon wish lists in their profile. Feel free to ignore it if you don't feel like giving them anything. But putting such links in your profile is no problem at all.

Comment: "But putting such links in your profile is not problem at all." ...putting them in comments or answers on the other hand...that's bad.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby Yep, which is why I referred to that. In such cases, flag the comment or edit it out I'd say.

Comment: I know of at least one *mod* who has a link to their Amazon wishlist in their profile. I wonder if that actually works...

Comment: Bribes @JonW, bribes...

Comment: @JonW Hasn't for non-mods, at least this one--only time anybody got me anything off my wishlist was when they explicitly and directly asked me what they could do for me and I panicked and created a wishlist.

Comment: "I panicked and created a whishlist" @DaveNewton. That just too funny. :)

Comment: @DaveNewton - dude, after checking out your list, I think I'd feel weird rewarding you with a knife or a face clamp...

Comment: Though the final book request puts it all into perspective @JoshDM ...

Comment: @JoshDM You guys should see my *private* wishlist!!! I does seem a little... scattered at the moment.

Comment: @Bart First I clamp them down...

Comment: Seat cover... Decanter... No can of fava beans...Do me a favor and don't answer any of my questions, OK? :-)